# How to handle infinity values in Python pandas and convert the rest of the column to float?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which contains 5 columns, one of which has multiple infinity values (in UTF-8 encoding). I use the following code to read the file and build a df

```
df = pd.read_csv(file,decimal=',',delimiter=';',header=[0,1],encoding = 'utf-8',low_memory=False)
infinity = df['Kanal C'].loc[250471]
print(infinity)
print (df)
print (df.dtypes)
```

The output, after I print the df and the dtypes is as follows

```
    (V)    ∞
Name: 250471, dtype: object
             Zeit   Kanal A   Kanal B      Kanal C   Kanal D
             (ms)       (V)       (V)          (V)       (V)
0      -10.000087  0.079202  0.031558  -2,38404300  0.159326
1      -10.000031  0.079202  0.047367  -2,38404300  0.000000
2       -9.999975  0.039524  0.063177  -2,38404300  0.000000
3       -9.999919  0.039524  0.063177  -2,46339800  0.159326
4       -9.999863  0.079202  0.015748  -2,54306100  0.000000
...           ...       ...       ...          ...       ...
892856  39.999846  0.039524  0.047367  -1,98665100  0.000000
892857  39.999902  0.039524  0.063177  -1,98665100  0.000000
892858  39.999958  0.039524  0.063177  -1,98665100  0.000000
892859  40.000014  0.039524  0.047367  -2,06600600  0.159326
892860  40.000070  0.039524  0.063177  -2,06600600  0.159326

[892861 rows x 5 columns]
Zeit     (ms)    float64
Kanal A  (V)     float64
Kanal B  (V)     float64
Kanal C  (V)      object
Kanal D  (V)     float64
dtype: object
```

Now the column named `Kanal C` has multiple infinity values and hence can not be converted to float. I have read and tried a lot of this to replace, delete, drop those values, and rows, but nothing worked. I would like to remove or replace all those 'infinity' characters from the dataframe and would like to convert KanalC to float like the rest of the columns.

Comment: `pd.to_numeric(df['Kanal C'], errors='coerce')`?

Comment: Yeah i tried this. I get the following error
TypeError: arg must be a list, tuple, 1-d array, or Series

Comment: Please include the output as text in the question, not as a picture, as this makes it harder for people to read on some devices or assistive technology

Comment: You say that you've tried to replace, delete, drop the values and rows, but you don't say what it is that you really want to achieve.

Comment: @Dragonthoughts point noted!

Comment: @DavidBuck i would like to delete/replace all the infinity characters and convert the column named 'Kanal C' into float, like the other columns (where is worked seamlessly with the code mentioned above).

Comment: With the point noted, please remove the picture in your question and replace it with the text, you can format it using the code syntax to keep columns signed up, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to define the infinity sign using python decode function and this solved most of my problems

```
inf = b'\xe2\x88\x9e'.decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: Your question is not about infinity values (`np.inf` and `-np.inf`) per se but more about handling the infinity character when reading from CSV.

Comment: yes. exactly. and due to the encoding, these characters could not be read properly. hence i just found the right encoding and defined the character using .decode